# Illustrator: save all open files as SVG with identical filenames

Tags: adobe-illustrator, export, svg, batch-processing

Is there a way to save all open files as SVG with some SVG options set with the same name as the Ai file?

Ex: I have fileA.ai, fileB.ai and fileC.ai open. I want to save all of these as SVG with CSS properties set to Presentation Attributes and they should have the same name as the Ai file. fileA.svg, fileB.svg and fileC.svg

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes there is a way you can make it.

following steps 
1st Make action for conversion
Open a single file
Go to window > actions
Create new action

[image]

A pop with name new action > mention name as conversion (if u want to set the function key u can select any key here we set f2) 
Click on **Record**

[image]

After clicking Record button the action start so be careful what step you perform will record so take in mind what step you follow 
Ctrl+A > Go to file > Save As > and change the format to svg (do not change the file name) click on save and another pop with svg Profile just click ok

After you finish the step go to action panel and click stop

[image]

Open all the ai files you want to convert

Go to action panel and there is a small arrow beside click on that and a drop down > click on batch

[image]

A pop-up > in action section select conversion

Source > select the folder > Choose the folder

In destination > select the folder > Choose the folder
and click ok

As soon as you click ok the process start and your file is converted.
[image]

Note : Next time you do not have to follow this steps, just open all the ai files and click the conversion and the play button.

[image]